# How to prevent browser autofill feature on HTML form?

Tags: html, forms

I am not talking about field **autocomplete** (when you click on the form's textbox and you get a dropdown with a list of previously entered values) but about the browser **autofill** feature that fills out the form with your personal data that browser saved previously (first, last, address, organization, phone, email, etc.). In chrome, autofill can be managed here: chrome://settings/autofill

People are using the terms autocomplete and autofill interchangeably, which adds to the confusion (I googled this to death). Everybody is talking about adding `autocomplete="off"` to your form or form input elements. That works for disabling autocomplete, but the browser's autofill feature still works.

For example, when I click on the telephone or email field, I get dropdowns with previous "entries," and clicking on any of the entries will fill out multiple fields in the form.

Is there way to disable autofill when designing form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: It doesn't. I've seen that post before. A lot of answers are outdated or simply treat autocomplete and autofill feature as one same thing.

Comment: @bobetko Did you get the solution? I am also facing the same problem and almost all the solutions are talking about the workaround. I don't see any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Put within  tag to prevent auto-fill within forms:

```
<form autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `autocomplete="chrome-off"` for Chrome versions below Chrome88, after that `autocomplete="off"` should stop autofill (implemented this January, actually).

Comment: Sadly Edge still does not honour this setting.

Answer (score 0):

All of the solutions above did not work for me.

Then, I thought that the browser saves the previous values based on the type of the field.

So, if I can switch the field type to a different kind e.g type="password" when I will actually use type="text";

So, once the first character is entered into the field, I will switch to the appropriate type and thus, browser will not be able to track that value.

This worked perfectly for me.

For example,

> Solution:

```js
<input name="password" type={password.length ? "text": "password"}/>
```

Depending on the framework or platform you are using, just dynamically assign the type using the example given above.

> Recreate the Problem

Ideally, browser is supposed to remember the last value by its name, but I guess it uses type instead.

For more context, check the code below:

1.

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" id="name"/>
<form/>
```

And

2.

```html
<form>
  <label for="school">School</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your school" id="school"/>
<form/>
```

If the first one has been rendered previously and, on another page, you render the second one, it will autofill with the value of the first one.